# Invoke receiver function declared in interface

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods

I'm trying to create an easy-to-use html generator for a personal project. I thought I would use extension functions to be able to generate an html programmatically using something like this:

```
html {
    head {
        title("Site title")
    }
    body {
        div {
            // stuff in div
        }
    }
}
```

For that I declared an interface:

```kotlin
fun interface TagBlock {
    operator fun Tag.invoke()
}
```

Where `Tag` would be the class designating the specific tags, like `html`, `body`, `div` etc:

```kotlin
class Tag(val name: String)
```

I now tried to create a function which accepts the earlier mentioned interface and returns a tag:

```kotlin
fun html(block: TagBlock): Tag {
    val html = Tag("html")
    // invoke `block` with `html`
    return html
}
```

I'm stuck on how to invoke the provided parameter `block`. The following all don't work:

```kotlin
block(html) // Unresolved reference
block.invoke(html) // unresolved reference
html.block() // Unresolved reference: block
```

Where am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `invoke()` operator you're declaring has 2 receivers:

- the *dispatch* receiver `TagBlock`
- the *explicit* receiver `Tag`

You need to provide the dispatch receiver in the context of your call for it to work. You can do this with the library function `with()`:

```kotlin
fun html(block: TagBlock): Tag {
    val html = Tag("html")
    with(block) {
        html.invoke()
    }
    return html
}
```

This may or may not be the usage experience you were looking for, though.

A more idiomatic approach in Kotlin would be to just take a function type as input:

```kotlin
fun html(block: Tag.() -> Unit): Tag {
    val html = Tag("html")
    html.block()
    return html
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I went with the idiomatic approach first, but then I had to introduce `Tag` subclasses, so I tried `typealias`, but sadly that doesn't support type-constraints, so I went with the custom `interface` to reduce redundancy across the whole project. But as I'm reading this, maybe I will go back to the "simpler" version with just a function-type. (a whole lot of *but*s I know)

Comment: @Lino with `Tag` subclasses, the approach with function types still works because the function can take the subclass of Tag as receiver (if you want more type constraints). Or if this is not sufficient you could even imagine using generic types as receivers. I probably don't have the full picture about what you're trying to do :)

Comment: I went with the idiomatic approach now, needs a bit more writing but it fulfills my needs. The case with the subclasses was to introduce more constraints for the user of these functions. I.e. a `html` tag would in my case only allow `head` and `body` tags, a `body` should not occur inside another `body`-tag, so with these generic constraints I would be able to allow only the specific tags I would choose. Another example would be the `title` tag which is only valid inside a `head` tag. I hope that clears things up a bit :)